# How to thin the disk

Tags: filesystem, disk-management

Suddenly I found my disk / is full, and I could not install any file on the system. So what directory can I go to remove some unnecessary files?  sda1 is bootable,,

```
shijie-ThinkPad-T410:/opt/pro/llvm$ df
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           779M  1.3M  777M   1% /run
**/dev/sda1        28G   28G     0 100% /**
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.8G  448K  3.8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   84K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda10      4.7G  4.2G  274M  94% /win
/dev/sda5        37G   28G  7.4G  79% /backup
/dev/sda8        25G   17G  6.7G  72% /vm
/dev/sda11       81G   52G   26G  67% /opt
/dev/sda7        28G   24G  2.6G  90% /home
/dev/sda6        82G   56G   23G  72% /other
```

Comment: I can see `23GB` Available in `sda6`,  `/dev/sda6        82G   56G   23G  72% /other`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what directory can I go to remove some unnecessary files?

`/`

All the other directories you show us with the `df` command are not part of `/` or are virtual filesystems.

And this depends on what you installed on your system. The generic places (like `/var/cache/archives/`  to delete the deb files it cached are temporary fixes.

28Gb is a lot for a desktop. If you have apache, mysql installed you will need more than 28Gb. If not you need to examine the software you installed on this system and start removing some. And the would be using the `apt purge` command, not a specific directory.

Comment: Thanks. There are some DB here.  By removing these DBs, I get 3G free space under sda1.